# python datetime.strptime AttributeError

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

print datetime.strptime("00", "%y").year
```

I would like to be able to pass "00" into datetime.strptime and receive "2000" as an output.  However, When I run code, I keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Answer (score 3):

`strptime` is not found directly at the level of the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module. It is a classmethod of the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) type inside the datetime module, so:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime("00", "%y").year
```

Comment: Even after using python for years, a class named datetime inside a module named datetime still makes me scratch my head sometimes